# Schedule Nintex Workflow on every 15th of the month querying SP List

Tags: nintex-workflow

I have a SP Custom List with events matrix. I have a Start Date, End Date. I would like to gather all the events from the list that has a start date between 15th of the current month to 15th of the next month and send email notification with details of all those events.

I would like to schedule this workflow to run on every 15th of the month.

Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: Please show us what you have done up until now. What does your list look like? What have you tried? You are new so this might be a good read for you http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

For this you would need to build a site workflow because this can be scheduled.

To get the workflow completed:
Step 1. From the workflow use the calculate date action to store the date variable to check for (I.E. between 15th and 15th). Step 2. Use the query list action to find all items (events) that meet that criteria. Step 3. Send email to owners/participant or whomever on those events.